# accessing nested dict fails

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dict which I construct over a period of several processes. To construct the dict I pass it to some functions, populate it and return it. With just a single entry the dict is constructed as such:

> {K: { K:V, K:V } }

For a near real world example:

```py
mydict = {"www.google.com": {"date":"1/1/19","text":"moo"},
          "www.yahoo.com": {"date":"1/2/19","text":"woof"}}
```

If I `print(mydict)` I see exactly as I would expect. However when I attempt to iterate through the dict I am unable to get the values from my nested dict by using the following:

```py
for k,v in mydict.items():
    print(mydict[k][text])
```

I instead get the error:

> NameError: name 'text' is not defined

But then when I perform the following it works:

```py
for k,v in mydict.items():
    print(mydict[k])
```

I am presented with results such as:

`{"date":"1/1/19","text":"moo"}`

`{"date":"1/2/19","text":"woof"}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh man alive! Its always so obvious once someone points it out.  Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote te "text" otherwise it's taken as variable name

```
print(mydict[k]['text'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `"text"` instead of `text`.

```
mydict = {"www.google.com":{"date":"1/1/19","text":"moo"},
      "www.yahoo.com":{"date":"1/2/19","text":"woof"}}

for k,v in mydict.items():
    print(mydict[k]["text"])
```

> **Output**

```
moo
woof
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `"` double quotes in your `text` : Here is the correct one

```py
for k,v in mydict.items():
    print(mydict[k]["text"])
```

Comment: He is not missing double quote. He is missing quote in general, be it single or double.